Removing Last Text Parentheses Using jQuery From a String
I am trying to remove the text from the last parentheses within a string using jQuery. I am able to remove the parentheses from the string but the code removes every parentheses and I need the last one to be removed only. For example, I have the following string "This is a (test) string (where) last parentheses (needs) to be (removed) "
I wrote the code below to remove the parentheses and text within the parentheses.
$('p').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, '');
});

The code I tried removed all the parentheses from within the string, I need to remove the last parentheses from within the string.

jQuery is not a tool for manipulating strings. Plain JavaScript is all you need.

lastIndexOf() might be useful here?

Can you try this;


var message = 'This is a (test) string (where) last parentheses (needs) to be (removed)';

message= message.replace(/\(([^()]*)\)$/,"$1");

console.log(message);




How will the expression looks like if last parantheses with text needs to be removed?

Then, use this: message= message.replace(/\(([^()]*)\)$/,"");

You need to update your regular expression a bit.

\(([^()]*)\): This part matches any content within a pair of parentheses.
(?=[^()]*$): This lookahead asserts that this pair of parentheses is the last one in the string. It checks that there are no more parentheses after the current match.

Your regexp: /\(([^()]*)\)(?=[^()]*$)/

The code still removes all parantheses from within the srting
